# How to maintain subcategory in MYSQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I am having categories as following,

- Fun

  - Jokes
  - Comedy
- Action

  - Movies
  - TV Shows

Now One video can have multiple categories or sub categories, let's say VideoId: 23 is present in Categories `Fun, Fun->Comedy, Action->TV Shows` but not in Action category. Now I am not getting idea that hwo should I maintain these categories in Database. Should I create only one column "`CategoryId AS VARCHAR`" in `Videos` and add category id as comma-separated values (1,3,4) like this but then how I will fetch the records if someone is browsing category Jokes?

Or should I create another table which will have videoId and categoryid, in that case if a Video is present in 3 different categories then 3 rows will be added to that new table

Please suggest some way of how to maintain categories for a particular record in the table

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You categories table could have a column in it called parentID that reference another entry in the categories table.  It would be a foreign key to itself.  NULL would represent a top-level category.  Something other then NULL would represent "I am a child category of this category".  You could assign a video to any category still, top-level, child, or somewhere inbetween.

Also, use autoincrement notnull integers for your primary keys, not varchar.  It's a performance consideration.

---

To answer your comment:
3 tables: Videos, Categories, and Video_Category

Video_Category would have VideoID and CategoryID columns.  The primary key would be a combination of the two columns (a compound primary key)

Comment: That I am maintaining properly, I want how should I maintain a video in different categories, if a video is in the 3 categories then, how I'll know that in how many categories a particular video is present???

Comment: Yups, the same solution I was thinking to create a new table "Video_Category", but I was not aware that I am doing it right or not. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It's exactly right.  It's referred to as a "Join Table" and is how you represent a many-to-many relationship in a database

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices, parentID (better as INT) to refer to the parent or an *extra table* with categoryID - parentID. 
The last one may provide a better logical separation and allows you to have multiple categories.

Comment: but if my video is in 3 or 4 or may be 5 different categories then, according to your answer, i'll have to add 5 columns to my table ??? If so, then it will not be an optimized solution, it will just fill my table with columns.....

Comment: sorry, I changed "columns" to table" ...
The core idea was the same as colithium now added to his original answer.

Comment: You can add n categories with m parent categories

Comment: The same applies for entries. Make an extra table with entryID and categoryID, then you can add every entry to all categories, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that create another table which will have videoId and categoryid. Then you can use sql-query as follow:

```
select a.*,GROUP_CONCAT(b.category_id) as cagegory_ids 
from table_video a
left join table_video_category b on a.video_id=b.video_id 
group by a.video_id
```